# Expectation of inequality

Tags: probability

I have an inequality of the form:

$$0 \leq f(x) \leq g(x)$$

And this is true for all $x \in \Omega$. Now let $x$ be distributed according to the pdf $p$. Is my reasoning that the following also holds correct?

$$E[f(x)] \leq E[g(x)]$$

Since:
$$f(x)p(x) \leq g(x)p(x)$$
$$\int_{\Omega}f(x)p(x)\,dx \leq \int_{\Omega}g(x)p(x)\,dx$$

And thus:

$$E[f(x)] \leq E[g(x)]$$

Comment: Well, if the integrals don’t converge, then the inequality  doesn’t hold. But if they do, I cannot imagine any pathological counterexample. Still, I’ll wait for someone more experienced with measure theory to weigh in.

Comment: As everything is positive, it's ok. Even if one integral diverges, the inequality holds. But if the signs vary, one integral can have no meaning. It would require, for example, a domination hypothesis from above and below for the result to remain.